# Google Drive - Android - upload image but don't convert to PDF

Tags: google, google-drive

I have just installed Google Drive latest Android application and notice that there is not a direct way to upload a camera image...

The only option I see is 'Scan', but after taking a picture I notice this is converted to a PDF. Is there any option to directly upload a camera image to Google Drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the gallery app , click the *share* option and you will see Google Drive appear - highlighted in pic below

[image]

If you want to automatically [back up and sync](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

> - Open the Google Photos app on your mobile device
> - At the top left, tap Menu
> - Select Settings > Back up & sync
>     At the top, switch it on or off.

Comment: On the iOS app you can directly upload a camera image to the Drive within the Drive app, I suppose this is not possible then?

Comment: My question was on how i can upload a camera image (image not pdf) from the Google Drive application itself. I suppose that is not possible?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you-  methods above work for pictures taken by you . First method is uploading single image from  gallery app where your camera pictures are stored. Second method is using Google Photos app which automatically upload all photos and videos to Google drive

Comment: I only have the Google Drive Android application, on iOS you can publish a image straight from the camera - on Android there is the option 'Scan' but it converts the image to a PDF. I don't want to use Google Photos...

Comment: If you mean using the Google drive, you need to go to *settings (of drive) and enable Google Photos- auto add* - if this is what you are looking for will add to answer. But you will need to have Google photos ( which you don't want)

Comment: Or use apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.drivesync) but what you are looking for is not possible in Android ( I am not familiar with iOS)